# How do I get my matchMedia to work inside of my resize event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I have TweenLite setting my startTrigger at x pixels depending on matchMedia sizing. I want this matchMedia to fire on browser resize so I added an event listener. It is not functioning as I have to reload the page for it to fire the matchMedia.

I've tried inserting the matchMedia code into my resize event listener which is also handling the top position of my element.

```
var triggerOffset2 = document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2 + 44;
var cardHeight2 = $('#card2').outerHeight(true) / 2 + 22;
var duration2 = 1000;
var requestId2 = null;  


window.addEventListener("resize", function() { 

var sceneStart2;
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)").matches) {
    sceneStart2 = 5000
  } else {
    sceneStart2 = 7000
  }
  console.log(sceneStart2);

    triggerOffset2 =  document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2 +  44;

    TweenLite.set(".contain2", {
        top: triggerOffset2 - cardHeight2

    });

    TweenLite.set(".timeline-trigger", {
        top: triggerOffset2
    });
});

var sceneStart2;
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)").matches) {
    sceneStart2 = 5000
  } else {
    sceneStart2 = 7000
  }
  console.log(sceneStart2);

TweenLite.set(".contain2", {
  top: triggerOffset2 - cardHeight2

});

TweenLite.set(".timeline-trigger", {
  top: triggerOffset2
});

TweenLite.set(".start-trigger", {
  top: sceneStart2
});

TweenLite.set(".end-trigger", {
  top: sceneStart2 + duration2
});


// SCROLL MAGIC!!!
var tl2 = new TimelineMax({ paused: true })
  .set(".card2", {  }, sceneStart2)
  .to(".card2", duration2, { rotationY: 180 }, sceneStart2)
  .set(".card2", {  })

// Only update on animation frames
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (!requestId2) {
    requestId2 = requestAnimationFrame(update2);
  }
});

update2();

// Set timeline time to scrollTop
function update2() {
  tl2.time(window.pageYOffset + triggerOffset2);
  requestId2 = null;
}
```

The matchMedia should fire when the browser is resized to change the top position of .contain2 and the number for sceneStart2

Comment: Have you included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` inside `<head>`?

Comment: Yeah. It is included.

Comment: triggerOffset2 doesn't seem to be defined as a var?

Comment: I'm able to get this working locally. Is your resize event actually firing? If so, what value is `matchMedia` returning?

Comment: @AndyHoffman the resize event is firing because it is adjusting the top position of .contain2 — the matchMedia fires on page load but not resize for some reason. I'm not sure how to find out what matchMedia is returning on resize. How can I find out?

Comment: @RachelGallen I've pasted the rest of the code to help with this

Answer (score 1):

Rather than binding `addEventListener` to `window`'s resize event, you should use the native `addListener` method `matchMedia` offers.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener):

> The addListener() method of the MediaQueryList interface adds a
>   listener to the MediaQueryListener that will run a custom callback
>   function in response to the media query status changing.

I would declare `sceneStart2` one time, at the top of your `JavaScript`. Its value will be updated by the built-in listener and you can remove all other `matchMedia` logic from your code.

Here's a stripped-down example for you to look at. With a little work, you should be able to integrate this into your code. To demo, open the "Full page" preview below.

```js
var sceneStart2;
var output = document.querySelector('.output > span');
var minWidthMatch = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)");

function getSceneStartValue(mediaQueryList) {
  sceneStart2 = mediaQueryList.matches ? 5000 : 7000;
  displayOutput();
}

function displayOutput() {
  output.innerHTML = sceneStart2;
}

minWidthMatch.addListener(getSceneStartValue);

window.onload = getSceneStartValue(minWidthMatch);
```

```css
span { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p>Resize the browser to dynamically change value.</p>
<div class="output">Value of <code>sceneStart2</code> = <span></span></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqecfghn/)

Comment: Thanks for the additional reading and the suggestion of the better way to do it. I'm working on implementing it now... still is only working on reload but I'm fiddling...

Comment: So I've modified by removing var output and the displayOutput() function. The window.onload is working because when I resize and refresh it is positioned correctly. Still not happening when I resize though.

Comment: @N.Thompson Can you create a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) project and include a link? I need to test the real application.

Comment: @N.Thompson Sorry this has been such a struggle for you. You should also be able to use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). There's a place in the left sidebar where you can add CDN links. Try that, and if it doesn't work, maybe we can use the screen share collaboration feature there.